# Checkbox not updating in react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, rendering, react-table

I've been learning and working on react lately. 
While creating a table using react-table component i've encountered a problem whit a checkbox I added to the headers of the table.

My main problem is that the checkboxes have a weir behaviour and it is not getting checked as it must have.

I've tried to save the items I have checked on an state object using useState hook.

`const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);`

Here is the header:

```
{
     Header: "CheckBox",
     accessor: "",
     Cell: ({ row }) => {
      return(<input 
              type="checkbox"
              checked={!isChecked(row.original)}
              onChange={() => checkBoxHandler(row.original)}/>
      )
     }
}
```

This is the function checkBoxHandler()

```
const checkBoxHandler = (row) =>{
        if(!isChecked(row)){
            const arr = [...selected];
            arr.push(row);
            setSelected(arr); 
        }
        else{
            const arr = [...selected];
            arr.splice(selected.indexOf(row),1);
            setSelected(arr);
        }
    }
```

And this is the isChecked() function

```
const isChecked = (row) =>{
        return (selected.includes(row));

    }
```

I would like to know if my logic has any problem or there is a more efficient way of implementing this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might just be a typo. You are not calling `setSelected` when checking the box in the handler.

```
const checkBoxHandler = (row) =>{
    if(!isChecked(row)){
        const arr = [...selected];
        arr.push(row);
        selected(arr);              // <--- here, this should also be setSelected
    }
    else{
        const arr = [...selected];
        arr.splice(selected.indexOf(row),1);
        setSelected(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Sady I tried changing that but the problem persist.